# Multiple Recursion

Tags: c

```
node *copy(node *T) {
  node *P;
  P = NULL;
  if (T != NULL) {
    P = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    P->data = T->data;
    P->left = copy(T->left);
    P->right = copy(T->right);
  }
  return (P);
}
```

How does recursion exactly work here?

When the Null condition is encountered, will it continue and go into the second recursion statement or start over again?

Comment: "When the Null condition is encountered, will it continue and go into the second recursion statement or start over again?" Neither.  Code returns `P` which is `NULL`.  Or is there something else that you have a question about?

Comment: This is program for copying tree Data structure . I wanted to know how exactly this works

Comment: A good way to understand how a C program works is to run it step by step in a debugger. So read [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: If T points to a proper linked list node, then this function does weird things duplicating every node twice or more - RECURSIVELY.

Answer (score 0):

The recursion statements are inside `if (T != NULL)`. So clearly none of that code will run when the null condition is encountered. This is what prevents infinite recursion: when you get to the leaves of the tree, it just returns `NULL` without doing any more copying.

All non-null nodes are copied by calling the function recursively.

Answer (score 0):

## No it will stop when NULL is encountered

### Working of Recursion:

Since, in every call of **copy(node *T)**, a **new node *P is declared**, so every left and right child of P copies corresponding left and right child of T until NULL is encountered in either sides.
In every function call of copy, the state of P is different. So, **P will have exact copy of T.**
You can **better understand the state of P by visualising the Stack of function calls**.

Hope it clears your doubt. :)

Answer (score -1):

This function is really weird if applied to a proper double linked list.
(A double linked list can be traversed in both directions, and quickly inserted or deleted in, thank to the fact that every node has a link to the previous (left?) and next (right?) ones).

Consider this list:

H = N1 = N2 = T

In the above line, the equal sign represents the double link, two lines, one to the right and one to the left, of every node.

If I invoke copy(N1), the function creates say C1, a copy of N1.
Then the function calls itself for the node left to N1: actually copy(H), which will create a copy of H and, subsequently, again a copy of N1 as N1 is the member to the right of H.

In a few seconds at best, the memory of any computer gets filled up.

This is true recursion!

UPDATE after comment.

Every time the node passed as arguments is not NULL, true recursion takes place. Of course, recursion must stop at a certain point, because otherwise it would be useless. In this case, recursion stops when the passed node is NULL.

My joke sentence about "true recursion" is about the fact that here there is a second level of recursion (if the function is fed with a double linked list), because every node gets duplicated more than once, in a recursive way. I duplicate a node, which makes duplicate of the siblings, which in turn call for duplicate the original node again, to the infinity.

Comment: When will the right recursion statement be executed? I get confused here.

Comment: I was talking about 2nd call of recursive function(to copy right sub tree). When is it called?

Comment: But why would you use a tree function on a list?

Comment: @GézaTörök: right, I only wanted to point out that such a function must not be used on a list, only on a tree with leaves. The OP never talked about trees. And of course, "don't use this function on a list" was exactly my point.